# How to define new variable based on multiple conditions in Pandas - dplyr case_when equivalent

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume that we have a `DataFrame` like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'var1': list('ABADDFGHIJI'), 'var2': [True, True, False, True, False, False, False, True, False, True, True]})

   var1   var2
0     A   True
1     B   True
2     A  False
3     D   True
4     D  False
5     F  False
6     G  False
7     H   True
8     I  False
9     J   True
10    I   True
```

Now, I'd like to define third column based on different combinations of values from `var1` and `var2` column. Here's my try:

```
df.assign(var3 = lambda x: np.select(
    [(x['var1'] in ['A', 'D', 'H', 'I']) & (x['var2'] == True),
     (x['var1'] in ['A', 'D', 'I']) & (x['var2'] == False),
     x['var1'] in ['B', 'F'],
     x['var1'] in ['G', 'J']],
    [1, 0, 0, np.nan]
))
```

However, this results in a following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

How can I quickly define new column based on these conditions?

Comment: look up pandas apply

Answer (score 0):

You are using Python `in` function which requires `truth-values` as it is shown in the error message. It is considered ambiguous in pandas so you should be using [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) function:

```
df["var3"] = np.select(
    [(df['var1'].isin(['A', 'D', 'H', 'I'])) & (df['var2'] == True),
     (df['var1'].isin(['A', 'D', 'I'])) & (df['var2'] == False),
     df['var1'].isin(['B', 'F']),
     df['var1'].isin(['G', 'J'])],
    [1, 0, 0, np.nan]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) to achieve similar things:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from datar.all import f, mutate, case_when, is_element, NA
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
...     {
...         "var1": list("ABADDFGHIJI"),
...         "var2": [True, True, False, True, False, False, False, True, False, True, True],
...     }
... )
>>> df
       var1   var2
   <object> <bool>
0         A   True
1         B   True
2         A  False
3         D   True
4         D  False
5         F  False
6         G  False
7         H   True
8         I  False
9         J   True
10        I   True
```

```py
>>> df >> mutate(var3=case_when(
...     # How you write in R (%in% is an alias of is.element() in R):
...     # var1 %in% c("A", "D", "H", "I") & var2 ~ 1,
...     is_element(f.var1, ["A", "D", "H", "I"]) & f.var2, 1,
...     # var1 %in% c("A", "D", "I") & !var2 ~ 1,
...     is_element(f.var1, ["A", "D", "I"] & ~f.var2),     0,
...     # var1 %in% c("B", "F") ~ 0,
...     is_element(f.var1, ["B", "F"]),                    0,
...     # var1 %in% c("G", "J") ~ NA,
...     is_element(f.var1, ["G", "J"]),                    NA,
...     # or for default values:
...     # True, NA
... ))
       var1   var2      var3
   <object> <bool> <float64>
0         A   True       1.0
1         B   True       0.0
2         A  False       NaN
3         D   True       1.0
4         D  False       NaN
5         F  False       0.0
6         G  False       NaN
7         H   True       1.0
8         I  False       NaN
9         J   True       NaN
10        I   True       1.0
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the `datar` package.